# Как получить количество определенных слов в определенной группе

Tags: sql, запрос

Есть колонка `extra_fields` в таблице `cat_items`. В этой колонке хранятся все характеристики материала. Но хранятся они в зашифрованном виде, например:

```
{"id":"1","value":"1"}
```

это означает `"id":"1"` = `"Страна"`, а `"value":"1"` = `"USA"`. В итоге имеем `"Страна:USA"`. А еще есть категории, например:

```
{"id":"3","value":"1"}
```

где `"id":"3"` = `"Категория"`, `"value":"1"` = `"Экономика"`. Получаем на странице `"Категория:Экономика"`.

Вот суть запроса: нужно вывести суммы категорий только страны USA. В итоге должны получить:

Экономика 12

Литература 36

Биология 65

и т.д.

Это все нужно для построения графиков. В SQL далеко не силен. Вот что придумал, но не додумал.

```
SELECT COUNT (extra_fields) AS extra_fields, '{"id":"1","value":"1"}' 
FROM cat_k2_items WHERE extra_fields LIKE '%{"id":"3","value":"1"}%'
UNION
SELECT COUNT (extra_fields) AS extra_fields, '{"id":"1","value":"1"}'
FROM cat_k2_items WHERE extra_fields LIKE '%{"id":"3","value":"2"}%'
```

В общем это не работает. Помогите советом, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Не очень много информации предоставили.
 Но если предположить, что в cat_items может содержаться только одна страна и только одна категория, то возможно поможет (в MS SQL):
 
`SELECT '{"id":"1","value":"1"}' AS Country ,
  SUBSTRING(cat_items, CHARINDEX('{"id":"3","value":', cat_items,0), CHARINDEX('}', cat_items, CHARINDEX('{"id":"3","value":', cat_items,0))- CHARINDEX('{"id":"3","value":', cat_items,0) + 1 ) AS Category,
  COUNT(cat_items) AS Cnt
FROM #Test
WHERE cat_items LIKE '%{"id":"1","value":"1"}%'
  AND cat_items LIKE '%{"id":"3","value":%'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(cat_items, CHARINDEX('{"id":"3","value":', cat_items,0), CHARINDEX('}', cat_items, CHARINDEX('{"id":"3","value":', cat_items,0)) - CHARINDEX('{"id":"3","value":', cat_items,0) + 1 )--'{"id":"3","value":"1"}'`